# `CallVirt` and `New` keyword

Tags: c#, .net, oop, clr

This question is linked to [How CLR calls methods correctly hidden by derived class when reference is stored in a base class variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017538/how-clr-calls-methods-correctly-hidden-by-derived-class-when-reference-is-stored)

In my case I'm using `callvirt`  instruction, not `call`

```
     class BaseClass
    {
        public void Write()
        {
            Method();
        }

        protected virtual void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base - Method");
        }
    }

    class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        private new void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
        BaseClass bcdc = new DerivedClass();

        dc.Write();
        bcdc.Write();

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Output:

```
 Base - Method
 Base - Method
```

IL code of `Write` method:

```
   .method public hidebysig instance void  Write() cil managed
   {
      // Code size       9 (0x9)
     .maxstack  8
     IL_0000:  nop
     IL_0001:  ldarg.0
     IL_0002:  callvirt   instance void Private_override.Program/BaseClass::Method()
     IL_0007:  nop
     IL_0008:  ret
   } // end of method BaseClass::Write
```

I don't understand here why `Base` method is called.

Here CLR uses `callvirt` instruction, which means that it's going to look for the calling variable type and since type is `DerivedClass` and `DerivedClass` hides `BaseClass.Method` then there should only be `DerivedClass.Method` in DerivedClass's MethodTable in the heap. Why `BaseClass.Method` is called? Is `callvirt` looks for specific `override` flags when it searches for methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you didn't `override` it. Change `new` to `override` and it will behave as you discuss (you'll have to change the accessibility to `protected` too, or it won't compile). `new` creates an **unrelated** method that just happens to share a name - it is not part of the polymorphism tree of other methods of the same name in base-classes.

You might as well ask: "why doesn't this call `CompletelyDifferentName()` ?"

```
class BaseClass
{
    public void Write()
    {
        Method();
    }

    protected virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base - Method");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    private void CompletelyDifferentName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method");
    }
}
```

The answer is the same: `CompletelyDifferentName` has nothing whatsoever to do with the `virtual` (polymorphic) method called `Method`. Well, neither does `new void Method()` - that is what the `new` *means* here.

Comment: I've marked `DerivedClass.Method` to override base method. in IL I see `.method family hidebysig virtual instance void Method() cil managed`. Does that mean that `callvirt` actually searches `virtual` keyword when looking for derived methods? With the `new` keyword IL is `.method private hidebysig instance void  Method() cil managed` - that is ordinary method.

Comment: @nikita: As all the others already said, 'new' creates an unrelated method that just happens to bear the same name, as opposite to 'override'. Hence, look: `private new void Method()`. This method is **normal**. It is ont virtual, it is just `private void Method()`, so the compiler has emitted an **ordinary** method. Had you written `private new virtual void Method()`, then it would create a virtual method. New, virtual, unrelated to the base virtual. Note that when you **override** then the created method is obviously automatically virtual. But, **new** does not imply 'virtual' in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is exactly how new should work.
New means that your new method has nothing in common with method with same name in base class.
It's the same as creating in derived class method with another name, just you use same name.
I.e. base class method write doesn't try to call new Methods, because it's not new version of Method in base, it's simply another member of the class.